# Centering numprint-formatted table columns

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

Consider the code shown below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{array, numprint}
\npstyleenglish

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{n{3}{0} n{3}{0} >{{\npunit{\%}}}n{2}{1}}
  {{\# successful}} & {{\# unsuccessful}} & {{\% successful}}\\
  528 & 472 & 52.8\\
  417 & 583 & 41.7
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Which typesets like so:

[image: Table with numprint-ed columns]

My question, thus, is, how do I go about centering the text in these columns? I tried many things and found no way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what happens with `numprint`. As a workaround, I suggest to achieve the same goal with `siunitx`, and additionally with `booktabs`. I would not write the `%`next to the numbers, as there's one in the column heading:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, siunitx, booktabs}
\sisetup{table-format=3.0}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ SSS[table-format=2.1]}
  \toprule
  {\# successful} & {{\# unsuccessful}} & {{\% successful}} \\
  \midrule
  528 & 472 & 52.8 \\
  417 & 583 & 41.7 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is `siunitx` able to round numbers and change decimal/thousand separators?

Comment: Yes: you have the `round-mode`, `round-precision`  keys (doc: § 5.5, Post-processing numbers, and `input-decimal-marker`, `output_decimal-marker` and `group-separator`. See § 5.6, Printing numbers, and §4.6 and §5.14, Tabular material.

Comment: Thank you. I have found `siunitx` to be of great use.